# How to display user's profile picture using email hash

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, gravatar

Previously, I worked in Laravel 5, there user's profile image was showing using `getHash()` of user's email. Now I am working in Laravel 8, but there is not showing user's profile image as previously showing. So, please tell me how I can display user's profile image using email hash in Laravel 8.

Comment: What do you mean by profile and avatar? Laravel never added user profile etc. by default as far as I know. You may have another package added to Laravel 5 project?

Comment: There's not enough information here. Please show us code of, what worked before in Laravel 5 and doesn't work now and also describe your upgrade process (related to this problem)

Comment: It sounds like you might be referring to [gravatars](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement), which uses an md5 hash of an email address to load the related profile image (if the user has registered on Gravatar).

Comment: Yes @KirkBeard, i am talking about gravatars.

Comment: Thanx @KirkBeard, i refer the link, you have shared. Actually i miss the code while creating app in laravel 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the steps to generate the URLs required to request gravatar profile images which i have missed while creating app in Laravel 8 -

1. Create a valid email hash.
2. Build the URL to request a profile image.
3. Append .php to that URL to indicate that you want the results in serialized PHP format.